mysqldump 8.0.22 doesn't output rows for a large table using where flag
I have a table which has a few hundred million rows and I'm trying to create backups using the mysqldump utility, version 8.0.22.
My entire command looks like the following (I've omitted the actual names of things, but the db/table names are alphabetical/underscores:
mysqldump -u[my username] -p --log-error=/home/[my user]/test/errors.txt --quick --single-transaction --set-gtid-purged=OFF --skip-add-drop-table --databases [my db] --tables [my large table] --result-file=/home/[my user]/test/out.sql --where="intID > 567000308" --verbose

When running the above from CLI, I am prompted for my password, then the utility works for ~10 seconds, and returns.
After, the errors.txt file contains the following output (which comes from the --verbose flag):
-- Connecting to localhost...
-- Starting transaction...
-- Setting savepoint...
-- Retrieving table structure for table [my large table]...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Rolling back to savepoint sp...
-- Releasing savepoint...
-- Disconnecting from localhost...

I haven't been able to find a way to get a log of the queries that mysqldump is sending to the DB, that'd be nice to have as I could probably step through things from there to get an idea of what's broken.
Once the utility runs, out.sql contains the following:
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.22, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: [my database]
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       8.0.22

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `[my large table]`
--

/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `[my large table]` (
    [column list here]
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=567000309 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `[my large table]`
--
-- WHERE:  intID > 567000308

LOCK TABLES `[my large table]` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `[my large table]` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `[my large table]` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2024-10-28 11:19:31

I never see a select query on my target table hitting the processlist while the utility runs, and the .sql file contains no data from the table.
Oddly, when I use the mysqldump utility for a different/smaller table, it functions correctly and the resulting .sql file contains the rows.
Additionally, I experimented with removing some of the flags from my mysqldump command, such as removing --quick and --single-transaction, but the behavior is the same.
I wasn't able to identify any known issues which would result in this behavior for this version of mysqldump.

have you checked if there are rows after 567000308

According to the dump information
CREATE TABLE `[my large table]` (
[column list here]
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=567000309 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `[my large table]`
--
-- WHERE: intID > 567000308

The [my large table] table has AUTO_INCREMENT=567000309, which means that the next inserted record will have the ID 567000309. You filter records with the condition intID > 567000308.
mysqldump worked correctly, there are simply no records in the table that match the condition.
